# How to prevent Joomla site creating unwanted folder

Tags: joomla3.0

I have a menu link with the alias "inside" on a joomla 3.1.5 site here: http://naiwellness.com

Every morning I check the site and a folder named "inside" has been created in the root dir which prevents the site from loading as it should, instead displaying a directory contents listing at http://naiwellness.com/inside

Anyone have any ideas how to prevent this please?

Thanks

Comment: Looks like the information you're providing isn't enough to perform any analysis to your issue. First, your site requires login, so not possible to see what's inside "inside", then what links to your "inside" menu - a module, component, article, what and what kind of script runs when "Inside" is selected from that menu? Providing complete information is crucial to get help, so please feel free to edit/update your question.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a theory, but check the xml files of your installed modules and plugins (most likely a plugin) for this line...

```
<folder>inside</folder>
```

and if it exists try deleting that line of code - or better still uninstall the extension - that should fix it. It's possible that a plugin requires that folder and has php code to create the folder if it doesn't exist - and so creates the folder each time it is run - i.e. when the site is loaded. The above line of xml code I have asked you to look for will go someway to helping determine if this is the case.